# Ajax submitting on login page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to the `PHP`. I am trying to code a project using `PHP` and `Ajax` to `logging` into another page. But in `Ajax query` some parts are not executing that means it check every thing inside the `Ajax query` part but shows always `"Wrong combination"` in `alert` whenever it success.

Here is the code that I tried:

Logging page `HTML` would be:

```
form method="POST" class="form-signin">
                        <div class="account-logo">
                            <img src="assets/img/logo-dark.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label> Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autofocus="" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-right">
                            <a href="forgot-password.html">Forgot your password?</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                            <input type="button" onClick="sendContact();" class="btn btn-primary account-btn" name="login" value="DO LOGIN" id="login_button">
                            <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary account-btn">Login</button> -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center register-link">
                            Don’t have an account? <a href="register.html">Register Now</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

The `Ajax` part would be:

```
function sendContact() {


    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    var data = {

        "email": email,
        "password": password,

    };

    jQuery.ajax({
        data: data,
        url: "auth/log.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST", // Type of request to be send, called as method

        success: function(data)
{
if(data==='success'){

    window.location.replace('index.php');
}
else{
alert('Wrong combination');

}

}

    });
    //  window.location.replace('index.php');


}
```

The log.php page would be

```
<?php

include "dbconnection.php";
session_start();

// $email=$_POST['email'];
// $password=$_POST['password'];

$select_data="select * from users where email='". $_POST['email']."' and password='".$_POST['password']."'";
$results= $conn->query($select_data);

if($results->num_rows>0){

$_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
$_SESSION["user"] = $email;


echo 'success';


}else{
    echo 'fail';

}

?>
```

Can some here help me.

Comment: `console.log(data)` and tell us what you see in your console.

Comment: @Taplar `if(data==='success'){` part always tell `success`. but it move to `else` part and execute alert `combination error`

Comment: If it goes to the `else`, that means the if is failing.  That is why I asked you to console log what the data is, and to tell us what value is being logged.

Comment: What can I do for this

Comment: Please add `console.log(data)` right before your `if` conditional, grab what it is logging in your console, and share with us the value that is logged.

Comment: It shows like this : `data = {email: "shahrukh123@gmail.com", password: "shahrukh"}`

Comment: You added the console.log **inside** the success method, right before the **if** statement and it logged that?

Comment: sure. I have added before. The results which mentioned you before. same as you told

Comment: If the logging of the data inside the success method is that object, then the code you have provided in the question does not match what you actually have.  The success method is written as `success: function(data) {}` so the data variable within that scope would not be the `var data` you created before the ajax call, which appears to be what you say the console log logged.

Comment: What can do for this